# Can it be said that an electron transfer between two neutral atoms comes from the neutral atomic electric field?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atoms, electronegativity

Let us consider the example of Na and Cl. Both atoms are called "neutral" simply because they have the same total number of protons as electrons, yet they have a very weak electric field which is hardly measurable. The electron transfer between two neutral atoms is ultimately driven by the electrostatic force.

Arguments like: This is because atoms and molecules are always trying to achieve the most stable, lowest energy state that they can don't really adress my problem, "lower energy" is not a fundamental force but the outcome of a process *caused by electrostatic force*.

So, in the end, can we say that this very weak electric field of a neutral atom is the main cause that it can attract electrons of other neutral atoms? Simply because the electrons are not classically like point charges in the same place as the protons?

Is there a more detailed book that deals with this in particular? Because I think this is fundamentally important.

Comment: While atoms do have zero net charge, the charge distribution is not generally spherically symmetric. And even it originally was for some atoms, like for 2 isolate H atoms, it stops to be, when 2 atoms approach. As the electrostatic potential stops to be spherically symmetric around their nuclei.

Comment: somewhat relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/267371/is-there-an-electric-field-around-neutral-atoms

Comment: @DrMoishePippik what should "quantum force" even mean? Thats not a fundamental force.

Comment: @Poutnik so can i really say that it is ultimately initiated by the weak electric field around a neutral atom and the more symmetrical the distribution the weaker this (already weak) electric field becomes? You meantioned it would break symmetrie a bit if 2 atoms approach, but this is somehow circular, because one of the 2 atoms must have been asymmetric by itself from the beginning.

Comment: It may help if you stop thinking about atoms as natural balls and start thinking there are positive nuclei and probability clouds of negatively charged electrons.

Comment: @Poutnik That could be, I have a picture in my head where there is a nucleus and a diffuse structure which over time is a distribution of many locations of an electron in the form of its orbital shape.

Comment: @Poutnik Theoretically, I could imagine a perfect symmetric electron distribution around a proton as a gaussian sphere. The perfect negative distribution on the surface of the sphere would be quantitatively equal to a negative electron charge at the point of the proton and thus really perfectly cancel the electric field. Such an atom would of course never react with anything in its environment.

Comment: Only if the electrostatic potential around proton is perfectly spherically symmetric. Is it?

Comment: @Poutnik no, of course not. That was just a hypothetical thought.

Comment: When your body hits some obstacle, you can tell yourself it was very weak, hardly measurable electrostatic force of neutral atoms. It may help the pain.

Comment: At molecular level, quantum effects become as, or more, important than electrostatic forces. Consider that if only electrostatic forces were acting on a hydrogen electron, it would fall into the nucleus. If the electron were orbiting the nucleus, it would radiate energy (being accelerated) and then fall in. See https://www.eetimes.com/quantum-wave-functions-come-alive-may-the-bohr-model-rest-in-peace/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to consider quantum mechanics to arrive at a rudimentary understanding of how two neutral objects containing charges can attract, but it is important nonetheless to understand that quantum mechanical properties are very different from classical ones, as explained for instance in answers in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290209/is-field-a-more-fundamental-quantity-or-forcein-classical-mechancis) post. In what follows I start with the classical picture.

Two neutral objects can attract each other because the cancellation of attractive and repulsive contributions from the positive and negative charges is not exact, particularly at close distances, and varies with distance. At long distances the total field of one object becomes very similar to that of a neutral point particle, and is therefore very small and nearly invariant with distance between the objects. Therefore both field and force are negligible. At close distances those contributions don't cancel, in particular because the strength of the field falls with distance. This is why two (real) dipoles can attract (ideal dipoles can only induce mutual alignment). To look into this in more detail you can consult the EM textbook by Griffiths.

What Fritz London et al accomplished was to place these basic ideas from EM on a more solid QM footing by introducing concepts such as the atomic polarizability. This was in part necessary because in the absence of point particles you need a different way of computing the field generated by the electrons.